# unable to sum a float iteration

Tags: ruby, sqlite, each, nomethoderror

`ruby -v 2.3.7` (sqlite3 has compatability issues with newer ruby -v)
`sqlite3 -v 3.22` `sqlite -v 2.8` `lsb_release -a 18.04`

I have condensed the code as much as I can.

```
def some_method(info_hash)
    ...
    db.results_as_hash = true
    sum = 0
    db.transaction
    db.execute2 "CREATE table if not exists a_table(Id INT PRIMARY KEY, Type TEXT, Month TEXT, Amount FLOAT, TOTAL FLOAT)"
    db.execute2 "INSERT into a_table(Type, Month, Amount) values(:Type , :Month , :Amount)", info_hash[:category], info_hash[:month], info_hash[:amount]
    get_amt =  db.prepare "SELECT Amount from a_table WHERE Type = :Type" 
    get_amt.execute info_hash[:category]
    get_amt.each do |g| 
        sum += g #here I get a NoMethodError for Nil:NilClass
    end
    db.execute2 "INSERT into bills(Total) values(:sum)", sum
    db.commit
    ...
end
```

I use mainly the `execute2` method.  I rely on the `execute` method where I need to ignore headers, such as in my `get_amt.each` block.

I want to `sum` the `Amount` column for `Type`.  But I run into a `NoMethodError` when I run my `block`.

The full error is:
`undefined method '+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`

**Please advise as to where I've gone wrong.**

**EDIT:**
I rewrote the code to reflect @Shawn 's suggestion:

```
def some_method(info_hash)
        ...
        db.transaction
        db.execute2 "CREATE table if not exists a_table(Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Type TEXT, Month TEXT, Amount FLOAT, Total FLOAT)"
        db.execute2 "INSERT into a_table(Type, Month, Amount) values(:Type , :Month , :Amount)", info_hash[:category], info_hash[:month], info_hash[:amount]
        get_amt =  db.execute2 "SELECT sum(Amount) from a_table WHERE Type = :Type", info_hash[:category]
        db.execute2 "INSERT into a_table(Total) values(:get_amt)", get_amt
        db.commit
        ...
end
```

This yields the `sqlite3 Exception` `Index out of range`

Comment: Ruby 2.7? [Are you sure about that?](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/releases/)

Comment: @anothermh sorry bout that typo (must have missed it about a dozen times !!!)  corrected

Comment: Sqlite **2.8**? ... why? That's from 2003!

Comment: And why not `SELECT sum(amount) FROM a_table WHERE ...`?

Comment: Oh! Are there any null values for amount in the returned rows?

Comment: @Shawn 1. just realized sqlite v myself!  wonder how that happened...upgrading now 2. Had not come across the `sum` method in sqlite3 yet (noob).Can u provide example?  3.no null values that I am aware of,

Comment: @Shawn I `sudo apt upgrade sqlite` was told I am running latest v.  checked `sqlite -v` = 2.8

Comment: The package name is sqlite3 on Debian/Ubuntu etc. And libsqlite3-dev if you're compiling the Ruby sqlite gem manually.

Comment: That's really really weird. The only way that error can happen is if `sum` is `nil`, regardless of what `g` is. Is this a real representation of your code, or is there more to it? Specifically, any way that `sum` would be `nil`, somewhere between `sum = 0` and that error?

Comment: @Amadan its real rep.  I opened up db browser only `total` is NULL bc `sum` isn't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.execute2 "INSERT into a_table(Total) values(:get_amt)", get_amt[1][0]
```

Essentially statement `get_amt = db.execute2 "SELECT sum(Amount) from a_table WHERE type = :type", hash_info[category]` writes more than 1 value into `get_amt` variable.
the variable must be provided with the`row` and `column` of the **specific** value that `INSERT` utilize.  Hence `get_amt[1][0]` Or the first row (next row after headers row) and the first column.